# Create ERDAS IMG Statistics using GDAL C++ API?

Tags: gdal, c++, statistics

I want to create very many ERDAS .img files using GDAL under C++. I don't want to have to process them all in ArcMap to create statistics for them (mainly because ArcMap fumbles when calculating statistics for very many input images in batch mode).  I want to create the .img files complete with statistics calculated for each.  I see python utilities for this, but nothing under the C++ API.  Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What is the context?  Are you making these datasets from scratch, or copying them from another source?

Answer (score 3):

GDALRasterBand::GetStatistics() should work for you after you create your datasets and bands, see:

http://gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html#a48883c1dae195b21b37b51b10e910f9b

if you are translating data, gdal_translate -stats forces calculation of stats.

Comment: Or better: [ComputeStatistics](http://gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html#a48883c1dae195b21b37b51b10e910f9b)

Comment: Sorry, was a typo.  My link points to ComputeStatistics, Mike is right.

Comment: I am creating these from scratch.  I'll work with GetStatistics().  Thanks very much.